# Decrease in value doesn't seem to be working in a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop

I have been struggling with this for hours.

I have a recursive function as detailed below:

```
void fractal ( turtle_t *t, int x){
  while ( x != 0){
    printf("%d\n", x);
    turtle_walk ( t, 20*x);
    turtle_turn ( t, 25 );
    x -= 2;
    fractal ( t, x );
  }
}
```

When I run this code, everything seems to work except the `x -= 2`.  I start with a value of 10 for the parameter x.  The print statements give me:

```
10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 2, 6, 4, 2, 2, etc
```

Am I missing something?

I have also tried using

```
fractal ( t, x-2 );
```

for the recursive call but that won't work either.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) to run your program step by step, query values of variables, and understand what is happening

Comment: the while loop controls the recursion.

Comment: Maybe you want `if` instead of `while`? BTW, what's the expected output?

Comment: These reason it goes from 10 to 8 is because x-=2 is working.

Comment: yes, 10 to 8 to 6 to 4 to 2.. but then it returns 2 when it should return 0 (and thus break the recursion)

Comment: What output did you expect? The output you posted matches the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
void fractal ( turtle_t *t, int x){
  if( x >= 0){
    printf("%d\n", x);
    turtle_walk ( t, 20*x);
    turtle_turn ( t, 25 );
    x -= 2;
    fractal ( t, x );
 }

}
```

Comment: `else return` is redundant; reaching the end of a void function returns anyway

Comment: This generates a very different sequence of numbers.  It's not wrong, except that it isn't what the question's about — counter except that it has been accepted as an answer, despite the lousy `else { return; }` which is completely redundant (the `if` statement returns after the `else` clause, just as if the `else` wasn't there).

Comment: Yes its redundant. The reason i used return to be in clear that it will return from there.

There are times when u r tired from a long day work. and if  u review someone's code it will be clear eventhough its not of use.. 

I will update and remove return.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should add print statements on entry and exit to the function, so you can see where the code goes.  It *is* working as coded — the `printf()` in the function is not executed when `x == 0`, of course.

Here's a simple adaptation of your code, with the extra printing.  It ignores the turtle parameter and the turtle operations.  It records the value of `x` on entry in `x0` so it can be printed on exit in particular (also printed on entry, for consistency).

```
#include <stdio.h>

static
void fractal(/*turtle_t *t,*/ int x)
{
    int x0 = x;
    printf("-->> %d\n", x0);
    while (x != 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", x);
        /*
        turtle_walk ( t, 20*x);
        turtle_turn ( t, 25 );
        */
        x -= 2;
        fractal(/*t,*/ x);
    }
    printf("<<-- %d\n", x0);
}

int main(void)
{
    fractal(10);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
-->> 10
10
-->> 8
8
-->> 6
6
-->> 4
4
-->> 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 4
4
-->> 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 6
6
-->> 4
4
-->> 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 4
4
-->> 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 8
8
-->> 6
6
-->> 4
4
-->> 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 4
4
-->> 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 6
6
-->> 4
4
-->> 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 4
4
-->> 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 2
2
-->> 0
<<-- 0
<<-- 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets try to see this code with an example.

```
void fractal ( turtle_t *t, int x){
  while ( x != 0){
    printf("%d\n", x);
    turtle_walk ( t, 20*x);
    turtle_turn ( t, 25 );
    x -= 2;
    fractal ( t, x );
  }
}
```

Lets say this function was called via

```
fractal(pTurtle, 4);
```

Lets call this the first stack frame, and how it would look is:

```
x = 4
enter the while loop since 4 != 0
print out 4
ignoring turtle_walk and turtle_turn for now
x is now 2
call the fractal function with pTurtle and 2
remember later we are not done with this function
```

Now it would create a second stack frame, which looks like the function call of fractal(pTurtle, 2)

```
x = 2
enter the while loop since 2 != 0
print out 2
ignoring turtle_walk and turtle_turn for now
x is now 0
call the fractal function with pTurtle and 0
```

And it would generate a third stack frame, so there would be a call of fractal like

```
fractal(pTurtle, 0)
```

Which would do nothing. But we aren't done yet. Now we are back in the second stack frame, aka the function that called fractal(pTurtle, 0), which now has a x = 0. So it would fail the conditional and be done.

Now we return back to the very first stack frame, which still has x = 2. So it would look through again and print 2 and do the same thing as the second stack frame.

So the output you probably get from your program with the prints is:

```
4
2
2
```

Comment: There's no need to fix what isn't broken. The `fractal` function prints a fractal doodle. Warden has given you the explanation how the loop dn recursion work. (Unless you have a clear idea what the function should achieve, but doesn't, that is, but my impression is that `fractal` isn't a function that you'ver written yourself.)

Comment: fractal is something that I have written myself.  I am obviously new to recursion and trying to make sense of this all.  I have explained what I think should happen, and I am still not clear on why what I think should happen, isn't happening.

Comment: @Scholarmate: " I have explained what I think should happen" No, you haven't; read your question again. You give the actual output and ask "Am I missing something?" You don't give the expected output. If that should be just a decreasing series of numbers, you should use either only recursion or only a loop. But it is not clear from the question. The answer you accepted uses only recursion. (That answer isn't very good in itself, but the answerer obviously was good at reading your mind.)

Answer (score 1):

> When I run this code, everything seems to work execpt the x -=2.

`x -=2` is working properly that why you are getting correct `printf` when you entered 10.

Look at this  `while ( x != 0)` . if x goes in negative this will cause infinite loop .
so change your loop condition to  `while ( x >= 0)` .